# Nonzero root of equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a condition so that a polynomial has at least one nonzero root?

Suppose we have the equation $$\sum_{i=0}^m \alpha_i x^i=0$$

Do the coefficients have to satisfy a specific condition so that there is a $y \neq 0$ that satisfies the equation?

Comment: $a_0\neq 0 \wedge a_i\neq 0$ for some $i$.

Comment: So when $\alpha_0=0$ does the equation has only the root $0$ ? @YoTengoUnLCD

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Actually, any couple of nonzero coefficients should grant a nonzero root. Well, if the difference of the exponents is odd you will have a nonzero real root, but in general you should have a nonzero complex root any time two coefficients are nonzero.

Comment: @MickG True, my bad!

Comment: So is it  $\alpha_i \neq 0 \land \alpha_j \neq 0$ ? @MickG

Comment: Yes @Mary, if there exist two indices $i\neq j$ such that $\alpha_i,\alpha_j\neq0$, there should always be at least one nonzero complex root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this and make it answered, here is a statement.

**Fact**

*A polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{0=1}^ma_ix^i$ has a nonzero root, i.e. there exists a nonzero complex root $y\neq0:p(y)=0$, iff there exist $i,j\in\{0,\dotsc,m\}$ with $i\neq j$ such that $a_i$ and $a_j$ are both nonzero.*

*Proof.*

Suppose the condition holds. Suppose wlog $i<j$, and that $i$ is the least integer for which $a_i\neq0$. Then:

$$p(x)=x^i\cdot\sum_{k=i}^ma_kx^{k-i}.$$

For $k=i$, the term in the sum is $a_i\neq0$, so that polinomial doesn't have 0 as a root. Yet by the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, and since the polinomial in that sum is nonconstant (as $a_j\neq0$ and $j\neq i$) it must have a complex root, in fact, it must have $m-i+1$ complex roots counted with multiplicity. Hence, $p$ has at least a nonzero root.

Suppose now that the condition does not hold, so for any two $i\neq j$ you have either $a_i=0$ or $a_j=0$. This means the polynomial is of the form:

$$p(x)=ax^k,$$

for some $a\in\mathbb{C},k\in\{0,\dotsc,m\}$. If $k=0$, then $p$ is constant and has no roots. Otherwise, the only root is 0.

$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)